# How can I change bucket name in MinIO?

Tags: minio

I have a Minio cluster that we you as on-promise object storage, We want to change bucket name in it, How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to rename buckets: you have to create a new bucket with the desired name, copy over your data `mc cp -r minio/oldbucket minio/newbucket` and delete the old bucket.

Answer (score 6):

IF:

- you are running a single instance minio
- you have access to the minio volume directly

Then, yes, it is simply possible by renaming the directory directly.

```bash
mv old-bucket.mydomain.example new-bucket.mydomain.example
```

**Explanation**

Let's assume minio data is stored in `/data/`, and we have a bucket called `old-bucket.mydomain.example`. Then the bucket is stored under `/data/old-bucket.mydomain.example` directory. Therefore, we can simply rename the directory and it would work!

---

**Update**

Please note that, there might be some issues in case of having encryption enabled on the bucket.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my single instance minio setup

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the directory does not alter the metadata.  Use the CLI.